# iPad- what directory for downloaded apps

Tags: ios8

On iPad, when a game, an app or whatever else is downloaded from App Store, it must be stored somewhere, but where? Where do they reside?

As test, I downloaded a game (2048) and an app (Skype) onto my iPad air with iOS8.

I my app (Xcode 6) I use the following code to enumerate all directories that I can think of but still am unable to find these downloaded stuff.

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSApplicationDirectory , NSAllDomainsMask, YES);

    for (id pathskey in paths)
    {

    NSFileManager *localFileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:pathskey];


    file = [[NSString alloc] init];

            while ((file = [dirEnum nextObject]))
             {
               NSLog(@"%@", file);
             }
    }
```

Any pointers?

Thank you

Comment: It's not supposed to expose those files. You can't access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user applications are stored in

/var/mobile/Applications

you won't be able to see that from your app because your app is sandboxed.

on a jailbroken device you could perhaps deploy your app directly into

/Applications

since running from there will have root access.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am wondering if I can do something with entitlements and/or powerbox (if at all possible for apps destined to run idevices)? If so how does one go about this?

Thank you